# There is already an object named xyz in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I created a View and saved it.  No problem.  Now, I'm trying to make a small change to the View and SQL Server is complaining that 'there is already an object named qry_faculty in the database'.  Yes.  Obviously there is.  I'm trying to change it and save it.

Is there some kind of setting that I can uncheck to get rid of this?

Comment: Are you sure you are doing an `ALTER` and not `CREATE`?

Comment: I did right-click and clicked 'Design'.  That's it.

Comment: Ugh!  I didn't change anything at all and now it works fine.  This is a brand new DB; setup last night.  All I can think of is that there was some kind of technical glitch that just worked it way out by itself.

Comment: You would do yourself a big favor in the long run if you write the view yourself instead of using the visual designer. That designer can make some horrible queries.

Comment: you might have created the view in the model database.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you use the ALTER VIEW command and not CREATE VIEW command since the view already exists. If you are using the query designer view I highly suggest you don't. Just find the view in the Object Explorer, right click, Script, Alter.